# Automatic Number Plate Recognition using tensorflow was working fine until I downloaded Cuda and it's other packages. How should I get it back to run?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The program was working fine until i installed CUDA. Now I get this error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_dtensor_device: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I have tried solving it by trying almost all the solutions posted on the internet, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

So I have just ran into the exact issue you have. So what I did was uninstalled anoconda and reinstalled it with tensorflow and everything, pretty much start from scratch. Then you need to find the zip files for your correct version of Cuda. https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive here is a link for every version, not including the 11.6. I also reinstalled cuda. While I used this link (https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download) to find the 11.6 version. Make sure you use the correct version or it will mess up so many things. Just copy the content of the bin of the zip into C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\bin. Let me know if this helps.